# Adding confirm javascript to asp.net generated links

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I have a number of buttons generated on the server, each of which is unique.

I want to be able to have a popup to ask if the user definitely wants to click, and then for it to follow through with the postback.

The generated button code is:

```
<a id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_btnID9994"
   href="javascript:__doPostBack('ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$btnID9994','')">
    <img src="mt_locked.gif"/>
</a>

<a id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_btnID9995"
   href="javascript:__doPostBack('ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$btnID9995','')">
    <img src="mt_locked.gif"/>
</a>
```

The buttons are generated using this method:

```
 objBtn.ID = "btnID" & room_id.ToString
 objBtn.CommandArgument = "Unblock"
 AddHandler objBtn.Click, AddressOf btnClicked
```

Is there anyway I can add the Confirm javascript code while generating the buttons above, so it will be rendered somewhere in here:

```
href="javascript:***confirm code here somewhere - if ok then continue to:... __doPostBack('ctl00
```

Thanks for any help,

Mark

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do when  generating button :

```
objBtn.Attributes.Add("onclick", " return confirm('confirmation message');");
```

or by client side, with jQuery

```
$(function(){
   $("a[id=*btnID]").click(function(){
      return confirm('confirmation message');
   });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I am sort of confused since you are saying buttons but the result is an `<a>`. Why dont you just use an ASP.NET Image Button.

**HTML**:

```
<asp:ImageButton runat="server" ID="btn_YourButton" ImageUrl="pathToImage" OnClick="btn_YourButton_Click" />
```

**Serverside**:

```
btn_YourButton.Attributes.Add("onclick", string.Format(@"javascript:; if(!confirm('Are you sure you want to delete the user ""{0}""?'))return false;", username));
```